# JAX-WS remove null value from List

Tags: jax-ws

i have webservice [JAX-WS] that contain this method :

```
 @WebMethod
    public List<String> getNumber() {
         List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
         s.add("test1");
         s.add("test2");
         s.add(null);
         return s; 
     }
```

also , i have webservice client that call above webservice.but when get List, size of list is 2.
how can i pass null value from webservice to client ?

Comment: I think, it's not possible with JAXB. What XML should be generated for you test? Do you want to benefit from `xsi:nil="true"` (see example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6831543/267197))? I am afraid that in this case you at least need to wrapyour list into response object, and use `@XmlElement(nillable=true)`.

Comment: find my problem , this is weblgoic 12c issue , everything goes right on glassfish.

Comment: If you have some time, just post the answer. Perhaps somebody will also get into this trouble.